# Issues using UTF-8 encode/decode (on some occasions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, codec

So, I'm having issues with Python3 encoding. I have a few bytes I want to work as strings. (long story)

In few words, this works

```
a = "\x85".encode()
print(a.decode())
```

But this doesn't

```
b = (0x85).to_bytes(1,"big")
print(b.decode())
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 0:
>   invalid start byte

I have read a handful of articles on the subject, but they insist that 'python3 is broken' or that 'you shouldn't be using strings for that'. Plenty articles on Stackoverflow just use "work arounds" (such as "use replace on error" or "user utc-16").

Could anyone tell me where the difference lies and why the function works while the second one doesn't? Shouldn't both of them work identically? Why can't utf-8 decode the byte on the second attempt?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case `'\x85'.encode()` encodes the Unicode code point U+0085 in the Python 3 default encoding of UTF-8.  So the output is the correct two-byte UTF-8 encoding of that code point:

```
>>> '\x85'.encode()
b'\xc2\x85'
```

Decode then works because it was correctly encoded in UTF-8 to begin with:

```
>>> b'\xc2\x85'.decode()
'\x85'
```

The second case is a complicated way of creating a single byte string:

```
>>> (0x85).to_bytes(1,'big')
b'\x85'
```

This byte string is not correctly encoded as UTF-8, so it fails to decode:

```
>>> b'\x85'.decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Python 3 is definitely not "broken".  It cleanly separates byte data from text. 
 If you have raw bytes, work with them as bytes.  Raw data in Python 3 is intended to be manipulated in byte strings or byte arrays.  Unicode strings are for text.  Decode bytes to text to manipulate it, then encode back to bytes to serialize to file, socket, database, etc.

If for some reason you feel the need to use Unicode strings for raw data, the first 256 code points of Unicode correspond to the `latin1` codec for 1:1 mapping of one to the other.

```
>>> '\x85'.encode('latin1')
b'\x85'
>>> b'\x85'.decode('latin1')
'\x85'
```

This is often used to correct programming errors due to encoding/decoding with the wrong encodings.